# ajax form postback with file upload controls

Tags: jquery, file, forms, upload, postback

I am currently using an iframe to support posting back a form that contains file upload controls (without requiring a full-page refresh).  Is there a more 'up-to-date' ajax mechanism these days for posting back a form in this way?  Does jquery ajax support file upload controls in forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) doesn't support file uploads (yet). 
The iFrame is the only way to do with stock HTML4.

You could try using a plugin like http://www.plupload.com/ that uses gears, flash, silverlight, html5 gears or html4 based on the browser.